# In-App Purchase track free monthly ususge Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am creating a android application where I have integrated In-App purchase functionality of Google.

Now I want to give following feature in the application.

**For the Paid service, If user not sub-scripted for the particular, user can access the functionality 1 time in a month**

I searched the docs n all but not able to tackle if this possible or not.

Thank you guys in advance